# web2py controller for layout.html

Tags: html, web2py

I'm building a web application using web2py, and have currently implemented search on some of the view/ pages by creating a function in the appropriate controller and then using {{=form}} to render it in my HTML page like this...

```
<h3>Search</h3>    
{{=form}}

{{if results:}}
<h3>Results</h3>

{{for result in results:}}
{{=A(result.title)}}
{{pass}}
```

Rather than repeat this functionality in multiple pages, I would like to have a search field in my layout.html file, which can then be used across all over views. However, there is no controller for layout.html. Is it possible to use a method in another controller in the layout.html page, or is there another way to link a controller to layout.html that I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the form? Does it search a database table, or does it produce results by some other means?

Comment: As I understand your problem: you can define the method to call and  return your results. like `return_result()`. So you could use a partial-html view that gets included into `layout.html` anytime you wish. Also `layout.html` is just the basic html-structure (aka page-layout) auf your application. Don't see it as "page".